# Graphical glitch

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-technic-pack

I was playing the [MoonQuest](http://www.technicpack.net/modpack/details/moonquest-yogscast-inspired.190904) modpack through the Technic Launcher yesterday, and after a long time of playing the game crashed. I started the game again, and suddenly all the textures went crazy. I have no idea what happened.
I checked vanilla Minecraft and everything was normal there.

Anyone know what's going on and how I can fix this?

Here are some screenshots:
[image: First]
[image: Second]
[image: Third]

Comment: It looks like the resource pack may have been corrupted (which seems odd to me).  Have you tried using another resource pack and seeing what it looks like?

Comment: @MBraedley I was using the BDCraft resource pack with patches for the specific mods and that one looked like this as well. I switched over to the vanilla texture pack and it was corrupt as well. So I'm sure it's not the resource pack.

Comment: My suggestion then would be to backup your world and download the modpack again.

Comment: I had the same error in vanilla. After i removed optifine, it works...

Comment: Are you having similar trouble in other games? Your GPU might be almost fried.

Answer (score -2):

Turn off anti-aliasing in (options) > (video settings) > (quality).